# Trying to build a drop down menu w/ animation start on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, css, lua

I've been trying to build this menu which starts as a little icon in the corner and on keypress (currently click) the checkbox is activated and thus starts the animation.

I have most of the menu + animation working now, I'm just stuck on how to activate it with a keypress. I want the key to be 'K' but no script seems to work for me. Here is all my code + whatever I could find to try and help me script the keypress.

```css
 /*////////////////
 // Jig Dropdown //
 ////////////////*/

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 311) { //this is the number code for the letter "K"
    document.getElementById('start').click();
    if (document.getElementById('start').className.indexOf("checkbox-checked") == -1) document.getElementById('start').className += ' checkbox-checked';
  }
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  document.getElementById('start').className = document.getElementById('start').className.replace(/button\-active/g, "");

}

function start() {
  console.log("start")
}

input[type=checkbox] {
 height: 1.5rem;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: .5rem;
 top: .5rem; 
 width: 1.5rem;
 z-index: 3;
}
#menu {
 background-color: #23272a;
 border-radius: 2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
 height: 2rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: .5rem;
 top: .5rem; 
 transition: .3s;
 width: 2rem;
 z-index: 1;
}
#line-one, #line-two {
 background: #949c9e;
 height: .2rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1rem;
 top: 1.1rem;
 transition: .3s;
 width: 1rem;
 z-index: 2;
}
#line-two {
 top: 1.6rem;
}

#icon-one, #icon-two, #icon-three {
 background: #23272a;
 border-radius: 1rem;
 height: 1.5rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: .75rem;
 top: 1rem;
 transition: .3s;
 transition-delay: .2s;
 width: 1.5rem;
 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}
#icon-one {
 background: #949c9e;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
 fill: white;
  height: 1rem;
 left: .37rem;
 position: absolute;
 top: .25rem;
 width: .8rem;
}
#icon-two {
 background: #949c9e;
}
#icon-three {
 background: #949c9e;
}
#icon-one:hover, #icon-two:hover, #icon-three:hover {
 right: 2rem;
 width: 13rem;
}

/*ANIMATION MECHANICS*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
 transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #icon-one {
 animation-name: jig-one;
 animation-delay: .4s;
 animation-duration: .3s;
 transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #icon-two {
 animation-name: jig-two;
 animation-delay: .45s;
 animation-duration: .3s;
 transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #icon-three {
 animation-name: jig-three;
 animation-delay: .5s;
 animation-duration: .3s;
 transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #line-one {
 background: #949c9e;
 top: 1.35rem;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #line-two {
 background: #949c9e;
 top: 1.35rem;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes jig-one {
 0% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)}
 33% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 2rem)}
 66% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 2rem)}
 100% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)}
}
@keyframes jig-two {
 0% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)}
 33% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 4rem)}
 66% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 4rem)}
 100% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)}
}
@keyframes jig-three {
 0% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)}
 33% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 6rem)}
 66% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 6rem)}
 100% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Menu Animations</title>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  </header>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\GTARP\FXServer-new\server-data\resources\[system]\mooseWallet\html">.
    <input type='checkbox'>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="line-one"></div>
    <div id="line-two"></div>
    <div id="icon-one">
      <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/82/82479.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
     </image>     
    </div>
    <div id="icon-two">
     <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25246.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
     </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="icon-three">
      <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61584.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
     </svg>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, the code for `k` is 75, not 311 and you should use the
  `keydown` event, not the `keypress` event.
- Next, in your `if` condition, each part needs to be a complete test.
- Also, you didn't have the checkbox have an `id` of `start`.
- Lastly, you've got some incorrect HTML (i.e. `link` elements must go
  in the `head` section and you have a closing `header` tag, but no
  opening `header` tag).

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which == 75 || e.keyCode == 75) { 
    // this is the number code for the letter "K"
    document.getElementById('start').click();
    if (document.getElementById('start').className.indexOf("checkbox-checked") == -1){ 
      document.getElementById('start').className += ' checkbox-checked';
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  document.getElementById('start').className = 
    document.getElementById('start').className.replace(/button\-active/g, "");
});

function start() {
  console.log("start")
}
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
 height: 1.5rem;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: .5rem;
 top: .5rem; 
 width: 1.5rem;
 z-index: 3;
}
#menu {
 background-color: #23272a;
 border-radius: 2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
 height: 2rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: .5rem;
 top: .5rem; 
 transition: .3s;
 width: 2rem;
 z-index: 1;
}
#line-one, #line-two {
 background: #949c9e;
 height: .2rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1rem;
 top: 1.1rem;
 transition: .3s;
 width: 1rem;
 z-index: 2;
}
#line-two {
 top: 1.6rem;
}

#icon-one, #icon-two, #icon-three {
 background: #23272a;
 border-radius: 1rem;
 height: 1.5rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: .75rem;
 top: 1rem;
 transition: .3s;
 transition-delay: .2s;
 width: 1.5rem;
 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}
#icon-one {
 background: #949c9e;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
 fill: white;
  height: 1rem;
 left: .37rem;
 position: absolute;
 top: .25rem;
 width: .8rem;
}
#icon-two {
 background: #949c9e;
}
#icon-three {
 background: #949c9e;
}
#icon-one:hover, #icon-two:hover, #icon-three:hover {
 right: 2rem;
 width: 13rem;
}

/*ANIMATION MECHANICS*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
 transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #icon-one {
 animation-name: jig-one;
 animation-delay: .4s;
 animation-duration: .3s;
 transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #icon-two {
 animation-name: jig-two;
 animation-delay: .45s;
 animation-duration: .3s;
 transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #icon-three {
 animation-name: jig-three;
 animation-delay: .5s;
 animation-duration: .3s;
 transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #line-one {
 background: #949c9e;
 top: 1.35rem;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #line-two {
 background: #949c9e;
 top: 1.35rem;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes jig-one {
 0% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)}
 33% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 2rem)}
 66% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 2rem)}
 100% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)}
}
@keyframes jig-two {
 0% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)}
 33% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 4rem)}
 66% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 4rem)}
 100% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)}
}
@keyframes jig-three {
 0% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)}
 33% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 6rem)}
 66% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 6rem)}
 100% {transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Menu Animations</title>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\GTARP\FXServer-new\server-data\resources\[system]\mooseWallet\html">    
 </head>
 <body>
    <input type='checkbox' id="start">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="line-one"></div>
    <div id="line-two"></div>
    <div id="icon-one">
      <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/82/82479.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
     </image>     
    </div>
    <div id="icon-two">
     <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25246.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
    </div>
    <div id="icon-three">
      <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61584.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much! Learnt a lot, i'm fairly new to coding so excuse the mess.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you forgot to put the id `"start"` onto your checkbox. Also, the keycode that I got for the 'k' key was 75. I have also used the key down event.

I have used `addEventListener` as opposed to setting the event properties directly, as this way you can have multiple handlers without them overwriting each other.

Good job on the animations! They look amazing and will really bring your website to life.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 75) {
    var startElem = document.getElementById('start');
    startElem.click();
  }
});
```

```css
  input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 1.5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5rem;
  top: .5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #23272a;
  border-radius: 2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5rem;
  top: .5rem;
  transition: .3s;
  width: 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

#line-one,
#line-two {
  background: #949c9e;
  height: .2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1.1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

#line-two {
  top: 1.6rem;
}

#icon-one,
#icon-two,
#icon-three {
  background: #23272a;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: .75rem;
  top: 1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
  width: 1.5rem;
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

#icon-one {
  background: #949c9e;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  fill: white;
  height: 1rem;
  left: .37rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: .25rem;
  width: .8rem;
}

#icon-two {
  background: #949c9e;
}

#icon-three {
  background: #949c9e;
}

#icon-one:hover,
#icon-two:hover,
#icon-three:hover {
  right: 2rem;
  width: 13rem;
}


/*ANIMATION MECHANICS*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#icon-one {
  animation-name: jig-one;
  animation-delay: .4s;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#icon-two {
  animation-name: jig-two;
  animation-delay: .45s;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#icon-three {
  animation-name: jig-three;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#line-one {
  background: #949c9e;
  top: 1.35rem;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#line-two {
  background: #949c9e;
  top: 1.35rem;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes jig-one {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 2rem)
  }
  66% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 2rem)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)
  }
}

@keyframes jig-two {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 4rem)
  }
  66% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 4rem)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)
  }
}

@keyframes jig-three {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 6rem)
  }
  66% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 6rem)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Menu Animations</title>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  </header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\GTARP\FXServer-new\server-data\resources\[system]\mooseWallet\html">.
  <input type='checkbox' id="start">
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="line-one"></div>
  <div id="line-two"></div>
  <div id="icon-one">
    <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/82/82479.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
    </image>
  </div>
  <div id="icon-two">
    <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25246.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="icon-three">
    <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61584.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
      </svg>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 75) {
    var startElem = document.getElementById('start');
    startElem.click();
  }
});
```

```css
  input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 1.5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5rem;
  top: .5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #23272a;
  border-radius: 2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5rem;
  top: .5rem;
  transition: .3s;
  width: 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

#line-one,
#line-two {
  background: #949c9e;
  height: .2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1.1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

#line-two {
  top: 1.6rem;
}

#icon-one,
#icon-two,
#icon-three {
  background: #23272a;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: .75rem;
  top: 1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
  width: 1.5rem;
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

#icon-one {
  background: #949c9e;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  fill: white;
  height: 1rem;
  left: .37rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: .25rem;
  width: .8rem;
}

#icon-two {
  background: #949c9e;
}

#icon-three {
  background: #949c9e;
}

#icon-one:hover,
#icon-two:hover,
#icon-three:hover {
  right: 2rem;
  width: 13rem;
}


/*ANIMATION MECHANICS*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#icon-one {
  animation-name: jig-one;
  animation-delay: .4s;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#icon-two {
  animation-name: jig-two;
  animation-delay: .45s;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#icon-three {
  animation-name: jig-three;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#line-one {
  background: #949c9e;
  top: 1.35rem;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#line-two {
  background: #949c9e;
  top: 1.35rem;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes jig-one {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 2rem)
  }
  66% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 2rem)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 2rem)
  }
}

@keyframes jig-two {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 4rem)
  }
  66% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 4rem)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 4rem)
  }
}

@keyframes jig-three {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0.1rem, 6rem)
  }
  66% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(-0.1rem, 6rem)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0, 6rem)
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Menu Animations</title>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  </header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\GTARP\FXServer-new\server-data\resources\[system]\mooseWallet\html">.
  <input type='checkbox' id="start">
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="line-one"></div>
  <div id="line-two"></div>
  <div id="icon-one">
    <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/82/82479.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
    </image>
  </div>
  <div id="icon-two">
    <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25246.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="icon-three">
    <image class="icon icon-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61584.svg">
      <symbol id="icon-image" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <title>image</title>
      </symbol>
      </svg>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```